# Where should I cleanup private resources for a ServiceHost?

Tags: c#, wcf, servicehost

I've set up a WCF NamedPipes Server/Client pair of applications but when the Host stops and calls `ServiceHost.Close()` it doesn't seem to appropriately cleanup the object from which the Host was created (using an object rather than a type to instantiate the host).

The server application code is as follows:

```
static void Main(string[] args) {
  // Specify the device type. Consider command line arguments here.
  DeviceTypes deviceType = DeviceTypes.myDeviceType;

  // Create the service object.
  ServiceHost selfHost = ServiceFactory.CreateService(deviceType);
  try {
    // Start the service.
    selfHost.Open();
    System.Console.WriteLine("The service is ready.");
    System.Console.WriteLine("Press <ENTER> to terminate service.");
    System.Console.WriteLine();
    System.Console.ReadLine();

    // Stop the service.
    System.Console.WriteLine("Closing the service.");
    selfHost.Close();
  } catch (CommunicationException e) {
    System.Console.WriteLine("An exception occurred: {0}", e.Message);
    selfHost.Abort();
  }
}
```

The `ServiceFactory.CreateService` method:

```
public static ServiceHost CreateService(DeviceTypes type) {
  // Create the client object.
  // Create_Server only creates an uninitialized child class based on the type.
  IMyServer client = MyServerFactory.Create_Server(type);

  // Initialize the client.
  client.Initialize();

  // Create the service object.
  MyService server = new MyService(client);

  // Create a service host.
  ServiceHost selfHost = new ServiceHost(server, new System.Uri(baseAddress));

  // Add a service endpoint.
  selfHost.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IMyActions), new NetNamedPipeBinding(), relAddress);
  return selfHost;
}
```

The `MyService` class (which contains the resource I want to clean up):

```
[ServiceBehavior(ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Single, InstanceContextMode = 
InstanceContextMode.Single)]
class MyService : IMyActions
{
    private IMyServer server;

    public MyService(IMyServer server) {
        this.server = server;
    }

    // Bunch of public operations to carry out the contract
    public bool Initialize() {
        return server.Initialize();
    }

    public void Dispose() {
        server.Dispose();
    }

    // No-op to check pipe connection.
    public void ConfirmConnection() { }
}
```

How and where should I call the `server.Dispose()` method in the `MyService` class?
I thought that this would be handled by `selfHost.Close()` but it seems not...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your output is a `ServiceHost` which is not a custom type you create.
Therefore it will not automatically call `IMyServer.Dispose()`.

Instead of returning a `ServiceHost`, create some kind of adapter that will manage the `ServiceHost` and your `IMyServer` instance and return it to the `void Main()` method.

Then, simply add a finally clause (or implement `IDisposable` and use `using`) and call your adapter's dispose, that will call `serviceHost.Dispose()` and `myServer.Dispose()`.